# Connecting to Qlik Sense to Apache Hive

Tags: qliksense, apache-hive

I would like to know , is there any other configuration that I can do to connect to Apache Hive from QlikSense, I am new to this, I would definitely appreciate if someone can help me to configure this. Thank you.

[image]